# How to call a custom input as method with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web3js

Im trying to build an app with web3js.

```
contractInstance.methods.totalSupply().call()
```

normally this code works and returns the value of the totalSupply method call.
But I get an input from console, and save it in a variable.

```
var meth = 'totalSupply()';
```

How can I execute the code above with this variables value?
I've tried

```
contractInstance.methods[meth].call());
```

but didn't work.

Can you help me please, thank you.

Comment: you can store a reference to the function in your object instead of stringifying it.
Something like `contractInstance.methods['keyForFunction'] = totalSupply`
Note, that there are no parantheses!
Calling the function would be as easy as `contractInstance.methods.keyForFunction()`
Storing a function call in a string is an anti pattern and can become a vulnerability threat.

Answer (score 2):

To invoke the method you’d need to select it by name (without the parens) and then invoke it.

```js
// "totalSupply"
const name = meth.replace('()', '');

// contractInstance.methods["totalSupply"]().call()
contractInstance.methods[name]().call();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the () that I've missed after "]... thanks again.